# LibreOffice graph axis label

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

I have made a graph out of about 20 lines of dates and 20 lines of values, but the graph doesn't show all the dates, which really bugs me, it just shows 'month' difference:

[image]

I would like to have more dates on the X axis (not all of them). Is there a way?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the source data (date/value pairs) to reproduce the chart? Maybe as csv?

Comment: Xlsl can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwm9y7cox5s05kj/statistics.xlsx (The graph there shows that I have made some attemps, but it only shows some more dates because I have streched it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display more dates on the X axis, there are different points to consider:

- choose a date format that's shorter than the current one;
- change text orientation of X axis labels;
- set a manual value for the scale's major and minor interval.
- select an x/y (scatter) diagram as tyle (instead of line - **this point is vital**, since this chart type offers additional options to format the X axis).

All this together may lead to a chart like this:

[image: new chart]

To apply those modifications, do the following:

- Select column `A`, right-click, select "`Format Cells`", select "`Date`" and choose a shorter date format;
- Right-click on the chart, select "Edit" from the context menu -> now, the file is in chart edit mode;
- Again, right-click on the chart, select "`Chart type`", select "`XY (Scatter)`" instead of "`Line`";

  [image]

Now, you can modify the labels on X axis:

- Double-Click on one of the dates of X axis to open the X axis properties (alternatively, right-click on one of the dates and select "`Format axis`";
- On the "`Scale`" tab, disable "`automatic`" from the "`Major interval`" / "`Minor interval count`", and the the major interval to "`2`";

  [image]
- On the "`Label`" tab, set the "`Text orientation`" to something like 60 degree.

  [image]

That's it. Hope the chart looks better now :-)